# Scroll Value not working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>jQuery 6</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #a1{
  background: aqua;
  width:80vw;
  height:80vh;
  }
  #a2{
  background: maroon;
  width:60vw;
  height:60vh;
  }
  #a3{
  background: magenta;
  width:40vw;
  height:40vh;
  } 
  #a4{
  background: green;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
  }
  #a5{
  background: purple;
  width:10vw;
  height:10vh;
  }
  #i11{
  position:fixed;
  }
  img{
   width:3vw;
   position:fixed;
   right:5px;
   bottom:5px;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a id="a1">
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "yellow")
   $("tr:even").css("background-color", "silver")
   /*$("input").blur(function(){
    alert('hello')
   })
   $("input").change(function(){
    $("table").hide(1000)
   })
   $("td").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide(2000)
   })*/
   //$("a").click(function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();
   //})
  // $("#a5").css("border", "4px dotted yellow")
   //$("#a5").parent().css("border", "4px dotted blue")
   //$("#a5").parents().css("border", "4px dotted red")
   //$("#a5").parentsUntil("aside").css("border", "4px dotted red")
   /*$("#b1").click(function(){
   if($("#t1").prop("checked")==true){
    $("#t1").prop("checked", false)
   }
   //else{
    $("#t1").prop("checked", true)
   }
   })*/
   $("img").hide();
   $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>120){
    $("i11").val($(this).scrollTop())
    $("img").fadeIn("slow")
   }
   else{
    $("img").fadeOut("slow")
   }
   })
  })
  
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" id="t1" />
  <button id="b1">check/uncheck</button>
  <input id="i11">
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Country</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://smentertainment.com">SM entertainment</td>
    <td>South Korea</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>BitCoin</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Marvel</td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>Vans</td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="a1">
   <div id="a2">
    <aside id="a3">
     <div id="a4">
      <div id="a5"></div>
     </div>
    </aside>
   </div>
  </div><a href="jquery6.html#a1"><img src="up.jpg">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>text<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>text
 </body>
</html>
```

So this is my full code, what i'm trying to do is to get the value in the input when scrolling, what has gone wrong here?

I've been checking the code over and over but the value just won't work. Then through the image i'm trying to get to the top of the page which works and so does the fade method.Is the problem within the function ?

Answer (score 1):

You missed `#` inside `$("i11").val($(this).scrollTop())` so this will be `$("#i11").val($(this).scrollTop())` please look below snippet:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>jQuery 6</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #a1{
  background: aqua;
  width:80vw;
  height:80vh;
  }
  #a2{
  background: maroon;
  width:60vw;
  height:60vh;
  }
  #a3{
  background: magenta;
  width:40vw;
  height:40vh;
  } 
  #a4{
  background: green;
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
  }
  #a5{
  background: purple;
  width:10vw;
  height:10vh;
  }
  #i11{
  position:fixed;
  }
  img{
   width:3vw;
   position:fixed;
   right:5px;
   bottom:5px;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a id="a1">
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "yellow")
   $("tr:even").css("background-color", "silver")
   /*$("input").blur(function(){
    alert('hello')
   })
   $("input").change(function(){
    $("table").hide(1000)
   })
   $("td").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide(2000)
   })*/
   //$("a").click(function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();
   //})
  // $("#a5").css("border", "4px dotted yellow")
   //$("#a5").parent().css("border", "4px dotted blue")
   //$("#a5").parents().css("border", "4px dotted red")
   //$("#a5").parentsUntil("aside").css("border", "4px dotted red")
   /*$("#b1").click(function(){
   if($("#t1").prop("checked")==true){
    $("#t1").prop("checked", false)
   }
   //else{
    $("#t1").prop("checked", true)
   }
   })*/
   $("img").hide();
   $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>120){
    $("#i11").val($(this).scrollTop())
    $("img").fadeIn("slow")
   }
   else{
    $("img").fadeOut("slow")
   }
   })
  })
  
  </script>
  <input type="checkbox" id="t1" />
  <button id="b1">check/uncheck</button>
  <input id="i11">
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Country</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://smentertainment.com">SM entertainment</td>
    <td>South Korea</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>BitCoin</td>
    <td>Japan</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Marvel</td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>Vans</td>
    <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="a1">
   <div id="a2">
    <aside id="a3">
     <div id="a4">
      <div id="a5"></div>
     </div>
    </aside>
   </div>
  </div><a href="jquery6.html#a1"><img src="up.jpg">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>text<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>text
 </body>
</html>
```